# Filter array of objects through checkboxes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox

This is a `React.js` filter problem and I'm stuck here. The problem has static data of movies as an array of objects and we have to filter that data according to the checked state of different checkboxes.

**Static Data:**

```
export const data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Batman',
        rating: 1,
        genre: 'Action'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Superman',
        rating: 5,
        genre: 'Comedy'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Spiderman',
        rating: 3,
        genre: 'Thriller'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        title: 'BananaMan',
        rating: 2,
        genre: 'Action'
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        title: 'OrangeMan',
        rating: 4,
        genre: 'Drama'
    }
];
```

The abstract UI has the following picture that represents 2 types of filters.

- Rating
- Genre

**Screenshot:**

[image: Filters screenshot]

Both Filters are rendered on the UI as checkboxes. So, I've created a component called `Checkboxes` which will take a prop named `list` and it is an array of objects.

This `list` represents unique `ids` of checkboxes which will help us to track the `checked` or `unchecked` state of the checkbox. The different checkboxes `id` will save inside the state which is an array.

```
const [checkedArray, setCheckedArray] = useState([]);
```

Finally, I'm rendering this `Checkboxes` component twice inside the parent component called `App.js`. One for rating and the other for genre.

**List:**

```
export const listCheckboxesRating = [
    {
        id: 0,
        name: 'rating',
        label: 'Any Rating'
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'rating1',
        label: 'Rating 1'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'rating2',
        label: 'Rating 2'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'rating3',
        label: 'Rating 3'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'rating4',
        label: 'Rating 4'
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        name: 'rating5',
        label: 'Rating 5'
    }
];

export const listCheckboxesGenre = [
    {
        id: 0,
        name: 'genre',
        label: 'Any Genre'
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'action',
        label: 'Action'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'comedy',
        label: 'Comedy'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'drama',
        label: 'Drama'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'thriller',
        label: 'Thriller'
    }
];
```

**Checkboxes component:**

```
import {useState} from 'react';
import {handleToggle} from '../../utils';

const Checkboxes = ({list, handleFilters}) => {
    const [checkedArray, setCheckedArray] = useState([]);

    const onChangeHandler = (checkboxId) => {
        const newState = handleToggle(checkboxId, checkedArray);
        setCheckedArray(newState);
        // Update this checked information into Parent Component
        handleFilters(newState);
    };

    return list.map((item, index) => {
        return (
            <div key={index}>
                <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    id={item.name}
                    checked={checkedArray.indexOf(item.id) !== -1}
                    onChange={() => onChangeHandler(item.id)}
                />
                <label htmlFor={item.name}>{item.label}</label>
            </div>
        );
    });
};

export default Checkboxes;
```

I'm passing the whole state of these checkboxes through a function named `handleFilters` to parent component `App.js`. You can see this line of code.

```
handleFilters(newState);
```

The `App.js` component is saving states of these checkboxes with something like this:

```
 const [selected, setSelected] = useState({
        rating: [],
        genre: []
    });
```

**App.js component:**

```
import {useState} from 'react';
import Checkboxes from './Checkboxes';
import {data, listCheckboxesRating, listCheckboxesGenre} from '../data';

const App = () => {
    const [movies, setMovies] = useState(data);
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState({
        rating: [],
        genre: []
    });

    /**
     * This function will perform the filtration process based on the key value.
     *
     * @param {number[]} checkboxState - It will take the final state of checkboxes
     * @param {string} key - It will help us to determine the type of filtration
     */
    const handleFilters = (checkboxState, key) => {
        const newFilters = {...selected};
        newFilters[key] = checkboxState;
        // Filtration process
        for (let key in newFilters) {
            if (
                newFilters.hasOwnProperty(key) &&
                Array.isArray(newFilters[key]) &&
                newFilters[key].length > 0
            ) {
                if (key === 'rating') {
                } else if (key === 'genre') {
                }
            }
        }

        // Save the filtered movies and update the state.
        //  setMovies();
        setSelected(newFilters);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            {movies.map((movie) => (
                <div key={movie.id}>
                    <div>Name: {movie.title}</div>
                    <div>Genre :{movie.genre}</div>
                    <div>Rating: {movie.rating}</div>
                    <hr />
                </div>
            ))}

            <div className="row">
                <div className="col">
                    <h1>Filter by Rating</h1>
                    <Checkboxes
                        list={listCheckboxesRating}
                        handleFilters={(checkboxState) =>
                            handleFilters(checkboxState, 'rating')
                        }
                    />
                </div>

                <div className="col">
                    <h1>Filter by Genre</h1>
                    <Checkboxes
                        list={listCheckboxesGenre}
                        handleFilters={(checkboxState) =>
                            handleFilters(checkboxState, 'genre')
                        }
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

The checkboxes `checked` or `unchecked` state of both filters are working fine and correctly updated with `ids` inside the parent `selected` state with something like this.

```
 const [selected, setSelected] = useState({
            rating: [1,2,3],
            genre: [2,4]
        });
```

But here is the confusing part where I'm stuck. How to map these checkboxes `ids` and filter the data according to these `ids`?

I've defined a function in the `App.js` component `handleFilters(checkboxState, key)` in which I wanted to iterate the `selected` state to perform the filtration process but my mind is not making logic and I need help.

**WORKING DEMO:**

[image: Edit react-filter]

[repository link](https://github.com/john45321/react-filter-problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some refactoring.

1. Made data more generic.

```
    export const listCheckboxesRating = {
      key: 'rating',
      data: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'rating1',
          label: 'Rating 1',
          value: 1
        },
        ...
    }
```

2. Refactor Checkbox component and just pass data.

```
    <Checkboxes
      list={listCheckboxesGenre}
      handleFilters={handleFilters}
    />
```

3. Made filtration process work with value and key.

```
    // Filtration process
    let filteredMovies = data.filter((movie) => {
      for (let key in newFilters) {
        if (
          newFilters.hasOwnProperty(key) &&
          Array.isArray(newFilters[key]) &&
          newFilters[key].length > 0
        ) {
          if (
            newFilters[key].findIndex((value) => movie[key] === value) === -1
          ) {
            return false;
          }
        }
      }
      return true;
    });
```

Working DEMO:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-filter-forked-gs2b2?file=/src/components/App.js

Answer (score 2):

So I had to do a couple changes in your code in order to address for proper filtering:

1. Added a `value` key on both `listCheckboxesRating` and `listCheckboxesGenre` to use it for filtering.

```
export const listCheckboxesGenre = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: 'genre',
    label: 'Any Genre',
    value: ''
  },
  ...
}
```

2. updated `onChangeHandler` to pass `value` back to `handleFilters` instead of the `id`

```
const onChangeHandler = (checkboxId) => {
    // ...
    handleFilters(newState.map((id) => list[id].value));
};
```

3. Created a couple filter functions to filter movies.

```
const handleFilters = (checkboxState, key) => {
  const newFilters = { ...selected };
  newFilters[key] = checkboxState;

  const hasFilters =
    newFilters.rating.length > 0 || newFilters.genre.length > 0;
  const filterRating = (module) =>
    newFilters.rating.includes(0) ||
    newFilters.rating.includes(module.rating);
  const filterGenre = (module) =>
    newFilters.genre.includes('') || newFilters.genre.includes(module.genre);

  const filteredMovies = data.filter(
    (m) => !hasFilters || filterRating(m) || filterGenre(m)
  );
  setMovies(filteredMovies);
  setSelected(newFilters);
};
```

**WORKING DEMO:**

[image: Edit react-filter (forked)]

Comment: I've checked this code but the `Genre` filtration is not working.

Comment: I think you're right, I forgot the first filter is not taking genre into account, let me fix that.

Comment: @VenNilson I created a copy of your codesandbox with a working demo.

Comment: It's great to add values to this list. One more thing when I choose `Rating 2` and genre `action` then the result should show only 1 movie instead of showing 2 movies in the result. I'm curious What is the reason for this?

Comment: Oh, that is basically because I'm going with a `OR logic`, you can try with the `AND logic` I left commented in the code.